# Creating custom URLs with template to fetch external JSON

Tags: templates, rewrite-rules, json, http-api

Hi guys hope you can help.

So I have a WP site and an external JSON enpoint (NOT from another WP) and what I want to achieve is to create dynamic "fake" URLs inside wordpress like: example.com/product/{{product_slug}} and upon entering this URL I want to fetch my JSON endpoint with that very slug, something like: externalsite.com/api/v1/product/{{product_slug}} inside a template for example single-product.php

I managed to achieve something like this with add_filter('template_inclide') and watching the url but this is so hackish.

I also found out that maybe I should use the add_rewrite_rule() but did not find out how to use it without redirect.

NOTE: I don't want to create custom post types.

If you need any other info on what I am triing to achieve please ask. I don't want you to write the code for me but to put me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was just really Friday for me.

Thanks to @eddiemoya and @matt-keys for their answers on [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58067/custom-plugin-route-in-wordpress).

Their answer helped me a lot. After their explanation I revisited the [Wordpress documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule#Using_Custom_Templates_with_custom_querystring) and it really wasn't that hard to comprehend.

The solution I user for my specific question was as follows:

1. I created a page inside WP. I named it Products (slug: example.com/products)
2. Created a template in my themes root directory and set a template name for it

   ```
   /** 
    * Template Name: My single product page
    */
   ```
3. Selected "My single product page" from the Template dropdown inside my Products page admin interface
4. Copied the page ID (1234)
5. In the functions.php I wrote the following code:

   ```
   funtion product_api_rewrite_tag() {
       add_rewrite_tag('%product_slug%', '([^&]+)');
   }

   function product_api_rewrite_rule() {
       add_rewrite_rule('^products/([^/]*)/?','index.php??page_id=1234&product_slug=$matches[1]','top');
   }

   add_action('init', 'product_api_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);
   add_action('init', 'product_api_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
   ```
6. Inside "My single product page" I can do something like this:

   ```
   global $wp_query;
   $pension_slug = $wp_query->query_vars['pension_slug'];

   echo $pension_slug;
   ```
7. Upon visitig example.com/products/my_new_product the template will return my_new_product.