# Routing in Wordpress

Tags: url-rewriting

I am using this [example](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58067/custom-plugin-route-in-wordpress) to rewrite url to load a given file `car-details.php` but I stil get error **Page not found**  when I access **domain.com/account/account_page/9**  How can I get this working.

```
class Your_Class
{

    public function init()
    {
        add_filter( 'template_include', array( $this, 'include_template' ) );
        add_filter( 'init', array( $this, 'rewrite_rules' ) );
    }

    public function include_template( $template )
    {
        //try and get the query var we registered in our query_vars() function
        $account_page = get_query_var( 'account_page' );

        //if the query var has data, we must be on the right page, load our custom template
        if ( $account_page ) {

            return CUSTOMER_CAR_PLUGIN_DIR.'pages/customer-car-details.php';
        }

        return $template;
    }

    public function flush_rules()
    {
        $this->rewrite_rules();

        flush_rewrite_rules();
    }

    public function rewrite_rules()
    {
        add_rewrite_rule( 'account/(.+?)/?$', 'index.php?account_page=$matches[1]', 'top');
        add_rewrite_tag( '%account_page%', '([^&]+)' );
    }

}

add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( new Your_Class, 'init' ) );

// One time activation functions
register_activation_hook( CUSTOMER_CAR_PLUGIN_DIR, array( new Your_Class, 'flush_rules' ) );
}
```

Comment: Could you please try this `domain.com/account/9` instead of this `domain.com/account/account_page/9`? `account_page` is your query variable it doesn't have to be in the query string.

Comment: same issue page not found.I have changed to `CUSTOMER_CAR_PLUGIN_DIR.'pages/customerxxx.php';` which doesn't exist in the plugin dir and could not throw error  file not found. I am loading a custom file from my plugin ,could that be the issue then?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding `query_vars` with [`add_rewrite_tag()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag), use the [`query_vars`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/query_vars) filter hook. I've used the following code to test your routing and it's working just fine.

```
class OP_Plugin {

    public function init() {
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'add_rewrite_rules' ) );
        add_filter( 'query_vars', array( $this, 'add_query_vars' ) );
        add_filter( 'template_include', array( $this, 'add_template' ) );
    }

    public function add_template( $template ) {
        $account_page = get_query_var( 'account_page' );
        if ( $account_page ) {
            echo "Working! \n";
            echo "Query: {$account_page}";
            // return CUSTOMER_CAR_PLUGIN_DIR.'pages/customer-car-details.php';
            return '';
        }
        return $template;
    }

    public function flush_rules() {
        $this->rewrite_rules();
        flush_rewrite_rules();
    }

    public function add_rewrite_rules() {
        add_rewrite_rule( 'account/(.+?)/?$', 'index.php?account_page=$matches[1]', 'top' );
    }

    public function add_query_vars( $vars ) {
        $vars[] = 'account_page';
        return $vars;
    }

}
$op_plugin = new OP_Plugin();
$op_plugin->init();
```

Comment: This does not work for me. I think you meant `$this->add_rewrite_rules();`, but even with that it doesn't work, at least not for me on WP 5.3 with nginx.

Comment: Flush your permalink settings then try

Comment: Yeah, I realized I had to do that after playing with it a bit. I was a bit confused by your `flush_rules` function, which actually isn't used. Also, this doesn't work with the OP's original routing (domain.com/account/account_page/9) - it returns "account_age/9", but like you mentioned in your comment above, it's better to use a route like **domain.com/account/9**, which does work.